# Allowing only those items which have real numbers inside my list box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having a dropdown and when i select item from dropdown my list box gets populated with set of items from json and some of items inside that list box are not having reak number value and I want only those items which have real numbers value ..below is my javascript.Please suggest

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "avb.json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(obj) {
            console.log("obj--", obj)
            var jsObject = obj;
            var usedNames = [];
            $('<option>', {
                text: 'Select your Option',
                value: '',
                selected: 'selected',
                disabled: 'disabled',
                location: 'fixed'
            }).appendTo('#dropdown1')
            $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                if (usedNames.indexOf(value.name) == -1) {

                    $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.name + "</option>");
                    usedNames.push(value.name);
                }
            });
            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) ){
                $('#listbox').toggle(this.value != "");
                }
            });

            $('#dropdown1').change(function() {


                $('#listbox').empty();

                $('<option>', {
                    text: 'Select your List Option',
                    value: '',
                    selected: 'selected',
                    disabled: 'disabled'
                }).appendTo('#listbox');

                var selection = $('#dropdown1 :selected').text();
                console.log("as".selection);
                $.each(jsObject, function(index, value) {
                    console.log("%o",value)
                    if (value['name'] == selection) {
                        var optionHtml = '';
                        for (var i = 1; i <=20; i++) {

                            var attr = 'attr' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);
                            var val = 'val' + ('000' + i).substr(-3);

                            optionHtml += '<option value="' + attr + '" data-val="'+value[val]+'">' + value[attr] + '</option>';

                        }


                        $("#listbox").css("width", "500px")

                        $("#listbox").css("height", "300px")
                        $('#listbox').append(optionHtml);
                        return false;
                    }
                    var selectedOption = $(this).find('option:selected');
                    console.log(selectedOption);

                });

            });
            $("#listbox").on("click", function() {

                console.log("asd", $('#listbox option:selected').attr('data-val'));
                var zxv =  $('#listbox option:selected').attr('data-val')

                $(".bar").attr("y",zxv)
                console.log("test", $(".bar").attr("y",zxv))
            //   $(".bar").attr("height",'100')

            })
        }
    });
});

my json
[ {
 "name": "ABC",
 "date": 1459461600000, 
"attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "60", 
"attr002": "SIGN2",
 "val002": "5",
 "attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00", 
"attr004": "SIGN4", 
"val004": "0",
"attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "Traesnotfound" 
}, 
{
"name": "ABC",
 "date": 1461176704000,
 "attr001": "SIGN1",
 "val001": "200", 
"attr002": "SIGN2", 
"val002": "70", 
"attr003": "SIGN3", 
"val003": "100.00",
 "attr004": "SIGN4",
 "val004": "670",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "Traceinvalid"
 }, 


 { "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459125900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
 "val001": "100", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "7",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "160",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "not found"
 },

 { "name": "XYZ",
 "date": 1459461600000,
 "attr001": "VISSE1", 
"val001": "50", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "70",
 "attr003": "VISSE3",
 "val003": "300.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "230",
  "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "found"
 },

{ "name": "XYZ", 
"date": 1459461900000, 
"attr001": "VISSE1",
"val001": "300", 
"attr002": "VISSE2",
 "val002": "10", 
"attr003": "VISSE3", 
"val003": "500.00",
 "attr004": "VISSE4",
 "val004": "350",
 "attr005": "SIGN5", 
"val005": "not found" } ]
```

Comment: Do you see this coloration good? Please add quotes where needed so it can help future readers along with me

Comment: I told you what to do: edit your post & add the missing quotes

Answer (score 0):

So you need a validation of your strings added to the control?

Try this one:
[Validate decimal numbers in JavaScript - IsNumeric()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

Comment: My problem is I want to include all real numbers (which include decimals and integers) not other things...i didnt get what is going in this given link..please explain

Answer (score 0):

You have to check value is number or not isNaN(value.name) this function will returns true if provided value is not number else false. Please look in  [isNaN() details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) this link for more details.

```
if (!isNaN(value.name) ) {
      $("#dropdown1").append("<option value=" + key + ">" +
                value.name + "</option>");
      usedNames.push(value.name);
}
```

To remove non decimal values from option call bellow function

```
function removeNonNumberEmptyOptions(){
   for(var i=0; i< $("#dropdown1 option").length;i++){
      if (isNaN($("#dropdown1 option")[i].value)){
          $("#dropdown1 option[value=" 
                     +$("#dropdown1 option")[i].value + "]").remove()
      }
   }
}
```

Checkout https://fiddle.jshell.net/6b9ne2y0/6/ link its working as per your expectations

you ware doing hardcoding for for loop it should be

```
 userPorperties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(value);
                for (var i = 0; i <= userPorperties.length -1; i++) {
                    if (!isNaN(value[userPorperties[i]]))
                      optionHtml += '<option value="' + userPorperties[i] + '"          
                      data-val="' + value[userPorperties[i]]  + '">' 
                      + userPorperties[i] + "=>" 
                      +value[userPorperties[i]]+ '</option>';

                }
```

Comment: .i have added the if statement above my list box but my list box still have the "sign5" item whose value is NAN not integer as u can see from json..why like this

Comment: If you do isNaN("attr005") it returns true, you have to call   $("#dropdown1 option[value=attr005]").remove(); iterate this for all items of list and your non number values get removed, try to add your code https://fiddle.jshell.net/ so i can look at it

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/6b9ne2y0/2/   my fiddle but dont know how should i refer to my json so i put at last of my script ..please have  a look